# Is conjunction omitted between noun and another noun

Tags: conjunctions

> Wall Street investment banks are like Las Vegas casinos: They set the odds. The customer who plays zero-sum games against them may win from time to time but never systematically, and never so spectacularly that he bankrupts the casino. Yet John Paulson had been a Wall Street customer. Here was the mirror image of the same **incompetence Meredith** Whitney was making her name pointing out.—*The Big Short: Inside the Doomsday Machine* by Michael Lewis—

Earlier in book, it said Meredith Whitney has said things that predicted fail of Citigroup due to their mismanaging business.

Is conjunction "where" omitted between incompetence and Meredith?

Comment: No, but the sentence is really pretty bad. It would be a "that" The idea is:  She made her name pointing out incompetence.

Comment: @Lambie I don't think the sentence is bad at all.

Comment: @Lambie So, how would you rephrase the whole sentence?  To me, it reads perfectly fine as is

Comment: @Lambie, Ok, so how would you *re-word" the sentence?  [And fixed]

Comment: @Kevin It's not the structure that bothers me and I can't change it's content really because I have not read it. It's just seems to me that if she was muck raking, which is fine, she had to be doing more than just "pointing out incompetence" to make a name for herself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same as "you did" modifying "boat" in:

> I painted a picture of the same boat you did.

So, no, there is no conjunction *missing*. "Meredith Whitney was making her name pointing out" is modifying "incompetence". You could *add* the conjunction "that" but it is not necessary and most style guides would recommend against it.

> Here was the mirror image of the same incompetence **that** Meredith Whitney was making her name pointing out.

Comment: There is an implied that between the two, which is not needed....

Comment: Does "pointing out" mean Whitney was pointing out incompetence?

Comment: @iceman Yes, that is what it means